# "Изображён" but "обезобра́жен" - Why does the stress in these words differ?

Tags: произношение, ударение

Today, I heard a radio newscaster pronounce `изображён` (depicted) as `изобра́жен` (**upd** - here is a [link](http://www.moskva.fm/share/4015/20130116/fromtime:09:18:55), check out 19:02). This definitely sounds wrong to me. To me, pronouncing this word with the stress on the last syllable (the de-facto standard) is the only form acceptable.

My first thought was that this was yet another example of a longstanding phenomena in the Russian language: words that are constantly spelled without "ё" finally lose the phoneme indicated by this letter. One well-known example is `Рерих`, who was actually `Рёрих` or `свёкла` which is pronounced by many as `свекла́` (or even as `свеколь` by some).

Then I realized that the main reason I find `изобра́жен` so cringe is that it actually sounds like another Russian word with the same root, `обезобра́жен` (disfigured). Contrary to `изображён`, the only linguistic norm I can recall is to pronounce `обезображен` with stress on the penultimate syllable.

So, my question is, where should I put stress in these words, and if the rules are different for them, which form is actually the original one? i.e. can we talk about a loss of `ё` here or vice versa? (or, maybe both forms have coexisted from the very beginning).

To put it simply (treat this as a sub-question): Did the form `обезображён` ever exist, and if it didn't, what are the rules that govern its stress pattern? Why, for example, do we say обнажён, изображён, and утверждён, but обезображен?

Comment: What kind of radio did you listen to, serious or not? Maybe that news presenter just tried to speak as fast as he could and while reading from the paper made a mistake and decided not to correct himself because he considered himself so cool and fast news presenter. See "День радио" movie, it can help you to understand how radio works in Russia.

Comment: @КуЪ - I've provided link so any one can check out I have not misheard it )

Comment: Very strange, he even makes an accent on this word. Maybe it is a kind of wordplay? Like Kotz is depicted but he looks ugly.

Comment: @KyЪ - quite possible. But I think it worth to mention here once again - question is about the origins of stress patterns and their evolution. Even if it was a joke, it was quite a clever joke, since it is using the fact that stressed differ in related words.

Comment: @shabunc Heh, you definitely heard it right. He even does an emphasis at that word. If it was a joke, it is only understandable for himself. What about stress patterns, I guess stresses tend to be arranged in such way that it is easier to pronounce the word and the sentence. I don't think it's possible to find out more general rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to pronounce those two words is : изображ**Ё**н and обезобр**А**жен. According to the modern orthoepic norm, this is the only possible variant.

The way we pronounce short participles in Russian depends on their long form. And the long form depends on the future form of the verb this participle was derived from. I'll quote an extract from the [prometod.ru](http://prometod.ru/index.php?type_page&katalog&id=890&met3) site :

> Страдательные причастия, образованные от глаголов, инфинитив которых
> заканчивается суффиксом -и-, подчиняются следующим правилам:

> 1. если ударение в личных формах простого будущего времени падает на
>    окончание, то ударение в полных формах страдательного причастия падает
>    на суффикс -онн-/-енн-:

> - заверш**И**ть, заверш**A**т — заверш**Ё**нный;
> - покор**И**ть,покор**Я**т — покор**Ё**нный.
>
> 2. если же ударение в личных формах простого будущего времени падает
>    на основу, то ударение в причастии предшествует суффиксу -енн-:

> - ув**И**дишь, ув**И**дят — ув**И**денный;
> - засл**У**жишь, засл**У**жат — засл**У**женный.

OK, then the question remains: why is the stress put in each **verb** differently if they both originate from the same root? Why do we say изобраз**И**шь but  обезобр**А**зишь?

I think it happens mostly due to the fact that the word **обезобразить** was formed from the adjective безобр**а**зный, which may have two different stresses depending on the meaning (i.e. these are actually two homographs, not one word.):

> Безобразный

> I. БЕЗО́БРАЗНЫЙ -ая, -ое; -зен, -зна, -зно. Лит. Не
> заключающий в себе образности. Б-ая речь автора. Б-ое мышление. ◁
> Безо́бразность, -и; ж.

> II. БЕЗОБРА́ЗНЫЙ -ая, -ое; -зен, -зна, -зно.
>
> 1. Отталкивающе некрасивый; уродливый. Б-ая ведьма. Б. вид. Б-ое платье.
> 2. Непристойный, возмутительный. Б. поступок. Б-ое поведение. Б-ая история.
> 3. Разг. Очень плохой, отвратительный, скверный. Доро́ги просто безобразны! ◁ Безобра́зно, нареч. Расходы б. велики (очень,
>    чрезвычайно). Безобра́зность, -и; ж. * Красота и безобразность
>    Разделены чертой одной (Пушкин).

> Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт С. А. Кузнецов. 1998

Probably the stress in the verb originates from the stress in the adjective. That stress was distinguishing two adjectives, and was so meaningful that remained in the verb.

So when we make a derivation of the verb обезобр**А**зить, it is **not** like this:

- **О**браз -->   обез-**O**браз-и-ть
  (prefix **обез-/обес-** means deprive smth./smb. of smth., in this case the verb would have the meaning "deprive of image/personality", or better "make plain" - лишить образа)

but rather like this:

- образ --> без-обр**A**з-н-ый --> безобр**A**з-и-ть --> о-безобразить
  (where the meaning of the verb is "make ugly" - сделать безобр**A**зным,    уродливым)

By the way, I haven't found any verbs derived from без**О**бразный. We may say "**лишить образности**" instead.

Answer (score 2):

По ссылке — утреннее развлекательное шоу, где ведущие шутят и дурачатся в прямом эфире, чтобы поднять настроение людям, собирающимся на работу. В таких шоу вполне допустимо исказить слово или ударение, сделать его "смешнее", чтобы привлечь внимание слушателей.

Правильно: изображён (ударение всегда на ё), обезобра́жен (всегда на а). Почему так?
Даже в словах с одним корнем ударение меняется: изображён, изображена́, изображено́.
Я думаю, нет общего правила, по которому можно определить, где должно быть ударение.

Например: зо́лото, боло́то, долото́ - только 1 гласная, а ударение на первый, второй или третий слог.

Comment: Прочтите, пожалуйста, вопрос, снова. Если он недостаточно ясен, я его отредактирую. Кроме того, ваш второй абзац непонятно зачем цитирует то, что и так цитируется в вопросе. И я НЕ спрашиваю о том, почему ведущий так сказал.

Comment: я убрал из ответа свой пересказ аудио по ссылке.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that news presenter just made a slip of the tongue? The two е/ё examples you provided in the second paragraph are quite common mistakes, but `изобра́жен` is something weird. It's even harder to pronounce. Could you remember what the context was?

Comment: yep, easily - человек изображен на фотографии. It nevertheless remains intereseting, whether there ever existed form "обезображён"

Comment: I heard about some psychedelic recommendations from Russian ministry of culture, such as `йогу́рт` and `кетчу́п`, but I'm sure it was just a slip of the tongue.

Comment: I guess they've tried to sound more french and, thus, to keep cultural tights  with russian XIXth century aristocracy )))

Answer (score 0):

Eugene already mentioned it. The rule of a thumb is that `ё` always gets stressed.

As a side note, it can image a pun where изображЁн (depicted) is pronounced similar to обезобрАжен (mutilated), i.e. изобрАжен or изобрАжён. Well, it's really hard to write a word with `ё` without meaning to stress this letter, for a pun you might even want to change `ё` to `е`.